# cell not replacing when i tap any cell in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

i have one switch control and that code is :

```
@IBAction func TappedOnSwitch(SelectUserType: UISwitch) {

        if SelectUserType.on{
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "PremiumUser")
            print("swifth on")


        }
        else
        {

            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "normalUser")
             print("swifth off")
        }
    }
```

Its printing well, in my console. Then i am checking this switch state and replacing the cell in my table view.

But its not working well. What i need is ? when switch is on i need to show `cell3` and when i switch off i need to show `cell2` .By default `cell` show be display in table view

Here is my code:

```
let premiumUserCheck = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("PremiumUser")
```

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     self.jsonParsingFromURL()

    let nib = UINib(nibName:"customCell", bundle: nil)

    tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")


    let nib1 = UINib(nibName:"Expandcell", bundle: nil)

    tableView.registerNib(nib1, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")



    let nib2 = UINib(nibName:"premiumUsercell", bundle: nil)

    tableView.registerNib(nib2, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell3")



}
```

Updated code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if(isTapped == true && indexPath == selectedIndex)
    {



        if (premiumUserCheck ) {

            let cell1:premiumUsercell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell3") as! premiumUsercell


                cell1.vendorName3.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name")   as? String
            cell1.vendorAdddress3.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address")   as? String

            return cell1


             print("premium user")
        }
        else {

        let cell2:ExpandCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell2") as! ExpandCell


        cell2.VendorName.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name")   as? String
        cell2.vendorAdress.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address")   as? String
        cell2.externalView.hidden = true

                   print("non premium user")
   return cell2
        }
    }
    else {



    let cell:customCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! customCell


    cell.vendorName.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("name")   as? String
    cell.vendorAddress.text=arrDict[indexPath.section] .valueForKey("address")   as? String

    return cell
      print("norml user")
    }

}
```

please help me out why its not replacing correctly??

Comment: Put your customCell code in the else block of this if,  if(isTapped == true && indexPath == selectedIndex)

Comment: sorry din't get you??

Comment: yes, i put that but still its not replacing with correct cell

Comment: please see my updated code

Comment: What exactly happening?

Comment: as my code, if user tap is true and if user is = premiumcheck "my premiumcell.xib " should show. And if user is not premium check my " expand cell should show

Comment: i am checking premiumcheck or not using switch

Comment: now at every time when i tap my `premiumcheckcell.xib` is showing

Comment: You are not reloading cells inside your TappedOnSwitch action.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107091/discussion-between-bharat-modi-and-user5513630).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your code as below,

```
if SelectUserType.on{

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "PremiumUser")
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    print("swifth on")


} else {

    //Here you were setting value for normalUser key instead of PremiumUser
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(false, forKey: "PremiumUser"/*"normalUser"*/)
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()
    print("swifth off")
}
```

Comment: actually in my table view controller dont have switch, when app start i have one view controller in that user have to switch on and off. So after that they have to press one show button , then it will redirect to another tableviewcontroller. In that only i have these cell code. so if i place `tableview reloadData` its getting error